# Mostar dados da tabela SQLite

Tags: php, sqlite

Quando apaga uma linha da base de dados, quando volto a atualizar, não mostra numa tabela que imprimo os resto das linhas, caso seja apagado no meio dos dados.

O problema é que tenho um `for` que corre todas as linhas da tabela pelo seu `id`, e caso por exemplo o `id=3` for apagado, e tiver mais registos, como `id=4,5,etc` só me vai mostrar ate o `id=2` porque tenho um `select` feito pelo `id`. Como posso resolver isso?

```
for($i=1;$i<=10;$i++){

        $requete    =   "SELECT * FROM contact WHERE (id=$i)";  
        $resultat   =   $base_hndl->query($requete);    // 
        $affiche    =   $resultat->fetchArray();
        echo "<tr align=center>";

            echo "<td>$affiche[id]</td>";
            echo "<td>$affiche[nom]</td>";
            echo "<td>$affiche[prenom]</td>";
            echo "<td>$affiche[fonction]</td>";
            echo "<td>$affiche[societe]</td>";
            echo "<td>$affiche[mobile]</td>";
            echo "</tr>";   

    }//fin de for
```

Comment: Por que ao invés de um `for` você não faz uma única query e usa a função `sqlite_fetch_array` em um `while` para percorrer o resultado, ao invés de fazer desse jeito complicado?

Comment: Da-me erro "Call to undefined function sqlite_open()"

Comment: A base de dados chama-se $base = $login."_vcf.sqlite"; e uso $dbhandle = sqlite_open('$base'); para abrir.

Comment: Em outro arquivo, tente executar a função `phpinfo();` e veja se a extensão do `sqlite` está ativa na versão do teu PHP, pois se não está encontrando a função `sqlite_open()` muito provavelmente a extensão não está ativa.

Comment: A extensão nao esta ativa.

Comment: Você tem acesso ao arquivo `php.ini`? Nesse arquivo, procure por `;extension=php_pdo.dll` e `;extension=php_sqlite.dll`. Remova o `;`.

Comment: Certo, dentro do ficheiro tirei o ; da ;extension=php_sqlite.dll e adicionei extension=php_pdo.dll, e reinicei o servidor. Continua a dar me o mesmo erro.